# JavaFX - How to fix 'fx:controller can only be applied to root element'

Tags: java, javafx, openjfx

I have created a simple borderless application with JavaFX. Now I created a Label which should replace the missing "close" button. Actually, my attempt is not working because I am not able to interact with my FXMLController.

I have already tried to add the FXMLController to my *.fxml file. I tried to insert the controller to the VBox and the AnchorPane but both are not working and I don't really get it.

**LabelCloseTest.fxml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<VBox prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="1025.0" 
    xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
      <children>
        <AnchorPane maxHeight="-1.0" maxWidth="-1.0" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" style="-fx-background-color: #303136;" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" fx:controller="com.mycompany.testing.FXMLDocumentController">
         <children>
            <Label fx:id="labelTest" layoutX="1007.0" layoutY="5.0" prefHeight="10.0" prefWidth="5.0" text="X" textFill="WHITE">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="13.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
         </children>
    </AnchorPane>
  </children>
</VBox>
```

**FXMLDocumentController.java**

```
package com.mycompany.testing;

import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

public class FXMLDocumentController {

@FXML
private Label labelTest;

@FXML
public void closeLabelPressed() {

       labelTest.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            System.exit(0);

             }
        });
    }
}
```

**LabelTest.java**

```
package com.mycompany.testing;


import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class LabelTest extends Application {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        launch(args);

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {


       primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
       FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/LabelCloseTest.fxml"));
       Parent root = loader.load();

       FXMLDocumentController fdc = new FXMLDocumentController();

       fdc.closeLabelPressed();


       Scene scene = new Scene(root);

       primaryStage.setScene(scene);
       primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

**Stacktrace**

```
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: fx:controller can only be applied to root element.
/D:/Workspace/SocketClient/target/classes/fxml/LabelCloseTest.fxml:10

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2621)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:917)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:980)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:227)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:752)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2722)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2552)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
    at com.mycompany.testing.LabelTest.start(LabelTest.java:25)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
```

I would expect that the application starts and when I press the "X" Label that the Application would close.

Quick reminder: I am new to JavaFX so I would also be thankful for every JavaFX tutorial recommendation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried to insert the controller to the VBox and the AnchorPane but both are not working and I don't really get it.

You mention trying to put the `fx:controller` attribute both on the `VBox` element as well as the `AnchorPane` element. The code you show is your attempt to add it to the `AnchorPane` element. Running your code on my computer as is results in the `LoadException` you observe. This problem is solved by putting the `fx:controller` attribute in the `VBox` element (the [root element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element)):

```xml
<VBox prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="1025.0" 
      xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
      fx:controller="com.mycompany.testing.FXMLDocumentController">
    <!--- Rest of FXML file omitted for brevity -->
```

---

***Note**: I initially noticed another problem where you weren't closing the `<VBox>` or `<children>` elements. However, those closing tags were there the whole time; they just weren't rendering in your question, [as pointed out by fabian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53925772/javafx-how-to-fix-fxcontroller-can-only-be-applied-to-root-element/53926918#comment94703004_53926918). I neglected to check for this.*

---

**However**, this results in a *different* exception.

```
// Beginning of stack trace omitted for brevity...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.mycompany.testing.FXMLDocumentController.closeLabelPressed(FXMLDocumentController.java:16)
        at com.mycompany.testing.LabelTest.start(LabelTest.java:28)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
        ... 1 more
```

This problem is ultimately caused by this code in `LabelTest#start`:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/LabelCloseTest.fxml"));
Parent root = loader.load();

FXMLDocumentController fdc = new FXMLDocumentController(); // the real problem

fdc.closeLabelPressed(); // accesses the labelTest field which is null
```

Since you're using `fx:controller` the `FXMLLoader` will create its *own* instance of `FXMLDocumentController`. It is this instance where the `@FXML` annotated fields get injected. You, on the other hand, create *your own* instance which will *not* have had the fields injected. You should be using the `FXMLDocumentController` instance created by the `FXMLLoader`.

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/LabelCloseTest.fxml"));
Parent root = loader.load();

// gets instance from FXMLLoader, must be called after load()
FXMLDocumentController fdc = loader.getController(); 

fdc.closeLabelPressed();
```

**However**, while your code (with the fixes so far) will do what you want it is not the correct way to do it. The method `closeLabelPressed` looks like you intend it to be an event handler since you annotated it with `@FXML`. You don't link this method with the FXML file, however, and instead the method adds an `EventHandler` to the `Label`. Set up correctly, you shouldn't be calling `closeLabelPressed` from `LabelTest` at all.

The first thing you should do is link the method to the `Label` via the FXML file.

```xml
<!-- previous omitted for brevity -->

<Label fx:id="labelTest" layoutX="1007.0" layoutY="5.0" prefHeight="10.0" prefWidth="5.0" text="X"
       textFill="WHITE" onMousePressed="#closeLabelPressed">

<!-- rest omitted for brevity -->
```

*Notice the `onMousePressed` attribute*.

The second thing to do is to change `closeLabelPressed` method in `FXMLDocumentController`.

```
package com.mycompany.testing;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;


public class FXMLDocumentController {

    @FXML
    private Label labelTest;

    @FXML
    private void closeLabelPressed(MouseEvent event) {
        Platform.exit();
    }
}
```

Now the method is called when the `Label` is pressed. Internally, the `FXMLLoader` sets the `onMousePressed` property (of `labelTest`) to an `EventHandler` that invokes `closeLabelPressed`. I've also changed the use of `System.exit(0)` to `Platform.exit()`. The latter will allow the JavaFX runtime to gracefully shutdown (allowing you to do clean up in places like `Application#stop`) while the former immediately terminates the JVM (and doesn't return normally). *Note: Injecting the `Label` may no longer be necessary*.

The third thing to do is to remove the call to `closeLabelPressed` in the `LabelTest.start` method.

After these changes your code should be working properly.

---

As for asking for tutorials (which is off-topic on Stack Overflow, see the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)) you can likely find many by searching Google. For "official" sources, see [JavaFX: Getting started with JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/index.html) (last updated for JavaFX 8) and [Introduction to FXML](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html). There are also [many questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fxml?sort=votes&pageSize=15) related to FXML here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Slaw Thanks for that detailed answer fixed my problem and I have really learned a lot by your answer! The only thing which scares me is that Scene Builder generated this FXML file. But anyways thanks for your great answer!

Comment: @Slaw the `</VBox>` was there the whole time. The code markup was not done properly though and since `</VBox>` was not considered part of the code block, it was removed completely from the rendered contents. (See diff for my edit.) This happens quite often with users not familiar with stackoverflow; It's often worth checking the markdown...

Comment: @csphmay The FXML was properly closed, actually, as _fabian_ points out. I neglected to check the raw markdown of your question to make sure it wasn't a formatting mistake.